# Should we work on creating tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was writing a question about taking pets to the vet, I wanted to add a tag about transporting, but we didn't have one.  I know we have questions about moving around with pets, so I looked at [moving](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moving). But that is not the right choice, finally I hit on [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) and that was what I needed.

We are getting a lot of questions from new users, so making the tagging system easier, by including more synonyms seems like a good idea.

I am not suggesting that we create more tags, I think we have a pretty good group now.  Synonyms create more paths to get the few tags.

I have not worked with synonyms in a while so I posted https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/travel/synonyms and read the rules on who can suggest and vote.

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

It is a moderately higher rep level, we only have about 40 users in the 1250+ rep count.  I am not sure how to count number of users with total answer score of 5+ on tags (to vote on proposed synonyms)

So I guess there are really two questions:

1. Should we make a focused attempt to improve synonyms?
2. Is our current membership sufficient to do the job with 'out of the box' tools, or do we need a custom approach?